# Encountering an error while calling get function using torpy in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tor

The following code works perfectly, thanks to @AKX

```
from pprint import pprint

sess = requests.Session()

# Do initial GET request, grab CSRF token
resp = sess.get("https://chartink.com/")
resp.raise_for_status()
csrf_token_m = re.search(r'<meta name="csrf-token" content="(.+?)" />', resp.text)

csrf_token = csrf_token_m.group(1)

# Do data query
resp = sess.post("https://chartink.com/screener/process",
                 data={"scan_clause":"( {cash} ( latest count( 90, 1 where latest ha-low > latest ichimoku cloud top( 9 , 26 , 52 ) ) = 90 ) )"},
                 headers={"Referer": "https://chartink.com/","x-csrf-token": csrf_token,"x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"})
resp.raise_for_status()
data = resp.json()
pprint(data)
```

But when I try an implement the same using torpy, I get an error message : "AttributeError: '_GeneratorContextManager' object has no attribute 'get'", on this statement `resp = sess.get("https://chartink.com/")`

```
req = TorRequests()
sess = req.get_session()

# Do initial GET request, grab CSRF token
resp = sess.get("https://chartink.com/")
resp.raise_for_status()

csrf_token_m = re.search(r'<meta name="csrf-token" content="(.+?)" />', resp.text)
csrf_token = csrf_token_m.group(1)

# Do data query
resp = sess.post("https://chartink.com/screener/process", data={"scan_clause": "( {cash} ( latest count( 90, 1 where latest ha-low > latest ichimoku cloud top( 9 , 26 , 52 ) ) = 90 ) )"},
                                    headers={"Referer": "https://chartink.com/", "x-csrf-token": csrf_token,
                                             "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"})
resp.raise_for_status()
pprint(resp.json())
```

Any ideas what's wrong here? Thanks

@AKX As per your suggestion, I changed the code and used the with statement and it worked. But I am not able to understand how it works with "with" and can the code be written without the "with" statement?

Here is the modified code:

```
with TorRequests() as req:
    with req.get_session() as sess:
        # Do initial GET request, grab CSRF token

        resp = sess.get("https://chartink.com/")
        resp.raise_for_status()

        csrf_token_m = re.search(r'<meta name="csrf-token" content="(.+?)" />', resp.text)
        csrf_token = csrf_token_m.group(1)

        # Do data query
        resp = sess.post("https://chartink.com/screener/process", data={"scan_clause": "( {cash} ( latest count( 90, 1 where latest ha-low > latest ichimoku cloud top( 9 , 26 , 52 ) ) = 90 ) )"},
                                            headers={"Referer": "https://chartink.com/", "x-csrf-token": csrf_token,
                                                     "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"})
        resp.raise_for_status()
        pprint(resp.json())
```

Comment: What is that particular library you're using?

Comment: It's , [torpy](https://github.com/torpyorg/torpy).

Comment: Well, the answer is simply that you need to use a with statement to use the sessions that library provides.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I changed the code and used the with statement and it worked. But I am not able to understand how it works with "with" and can the code be written without the "with" statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `with ...` with [torpy's TorRequests](https://github.com/torpyorg/torpy/blob/master/torpy/http/requests.py#L32), since [the `__enter__()` function (which is what `with` uses) is used to open the Tor connection for the session](https://github.com/torpyorg/torpy/blob/master/torpy/http/requests.py#L38-L42).

The library does provide a functionally equivalent helper context manager `tor_requests_session()`, so instead of

```
with TorRequests() as req:
    with req.get_session() as sess:
```

you can do

```
from torpy.requests import tor_requests_session

with tor_requests_session() as sess:
```

You *could* write the code without using the `with` block (a hint as to how is one of the links above), but you really should not. Besides, there's no good reason to - just formulate your program to use functions á la

```
def get_chartink_data(sess):
    # ...

def main():
    with tor_requests_session() as sess:
        data = get_chartink_data(sess)
    # ...
```

and you don't really need to care about that `with`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AKX. Your explanation is very insightful.

Comment: I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torpy.requests'`

Comment: @InnocentBystander Then you should probably install `torpy`?